# Get Max And Min dates for consecutive values in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions, gaps-and-islands, date-arithmetic

I have a log table like below and want to simplfy it by getting min start date and max end date for consecutive Status values for each Id. I tried many window function combinations but no luck.

This is what I have:

[image]

This is what want to see:

[image]

Comment: Search gaps and islands.

Comment: What have you tried? How to ask good questions... https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It would be nice to complement your question a little more, but so quickly you could try to make a group using a `Group by`

Comment: If you wish to improve your question replace the images with text data. For bonus point use DDL/DML statements to build temp tables people can use for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical gaps-and-islands problem. You want to aggregate groups of consecutive records that have the same `Id` and `Status`.

No need for recursion, here is one way to solve it using window functions:

```
select
    Id,
    Status,
    min(StartDate) StartDate,
    max(EndDate) EndDate
from (
    select
        t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by id order by StartDate) rn1,
        row_number() over(partition by id, status order by StartDate) rn2
    from mytable t
) t
group by
    Id,
    Status,
    rn1 - rn2
order by Id, min(StartDate)
```

The query works by ranking records over two different partitions (by `Id`, and by `Id` *and* `Status`). The difference between the ranks gives you the group each record belongs to. You can run the subquery independently to see what it returns and understand the logic.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6fa5e3912c430450bfacfcca5f74a38a)**:

```
Id | Status | StartDate           | EndDate            
-: | :----- | :------------------ | :------------------
 1 | B      | 07/02/2019 00:00:00 | 18/02/2019 00:00:00
 1 | C      | 18/02/2019 00:00:00 | 10/03/2019 00:00:00
 1 | B      | 10/03/2019 00:00:00 | 01/04/2019 00:00:00
 2 | A      | 05/02/2019 00:00:00 | 22/04/2019 00:00:00
 2 | D      | 22/04/2019 00:00:00 | 05/05/2019 00:00:00
 2 | A      | 05/05/2019 00:00:00 | 30/06/2019 00:00:00
```

Comment: Nice. It's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following query. First order the data by StartDate and generate a sequence (rid). Then you the recursive cte to get the first row (rid=1) for each group (id,status), and recursively get the next row and compare the start/end date.

```
;WITH cte_r(id,[Status],StartDate,EndDate,rid)
AS
(
SELECT id,[Status],StartDate,EndDate, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Id,[Status] ORDER BY StartDate) AS rid
FROM log_table 
),
cte_range(id,[Status],StartDate,EndDate,rid)
AS
(
  SELECT id,[Status],StartDate,EndDate,rid
  FROM cte_r
  WHERE rid=1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT p.id, p.[Status], CASE WHEN c.StartDate<p.EndDate THEN p.StartDate ELSE c.StartDate END AS StartDate, c.EndDate,c.rid
  FROM cte_range p
  INNER JOIN cte_r c
  ON p.id=c.id
  AND p.[Status]=c.[Status]
  AND p.rid+1=c.rid
 )
 SELECT id,[Status],StartDate,MAX(EndDate) AS EndDate FROM cte_range GROUP BY id,StartDate ;
```